# Now what after authorizing credit card in 2checkout?

Tags: django, 2checkout

I went through [this](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/tutorial) tutorial to integrate 2checkout to my django project.

When I enter the proper credit card info, it is returning this message:

**Successfully authorized the provided credit card**

Does this mean that payment was carried out?

What is next? Should I just give this message to the user and that is it? or what?

**EDIT:**
    this is what I am sending to 2checkout, after getting the token

```
args = {
        'merchantOrderId': '123',
        'token': request.POST["token"],
        'currency': 'USD',
        'total': '5.89',
        'billingAddr': {
            'name': 'Testing Tester',
            'addrLine1': '123 Test St',
            'city': 'Columbus',
            'state': 'OH',
            'zipCode': '43123',
            'country': 'USA',
            'email': 'example@2co.com',
            'phoneNumber': '555-555-5555'
        }
    }

result = twocheckout.Charge.authorize(args)
```

This is what result includes (**dict(result)**):

```
{u'responseMsg': u'Successfully authorized the provided credit card', u'responseCode': u'APPROVED', u'shippingAddr': {u'city': None, u'phoneExtension': None, u'country': None, u'addrLine2': None, u'zipCode': None, u'addrLine1': None, u'state': None, u'phoneNumber': None, u'email': None, u'name': None}, u'orderNumber': u'9093719318841', u'currencyCode': u'USD', u'merchantOrderId': u'123', u'errors': None, u'recurrentInstallmentId': None, u'total': u'5.89', u'transactionId': u'9093719318850', u'lineItems': [{u'tangible': u'N', u'description': u'', u'quantity': u'1', u'type': u'product', u'price': u'5.89', u'recurrence': None, u'duration': None, u'productId': u'', u'startupFee': None, u'options': [], u'name': u'123'}], u'type': u'AuthResponse', u'billingAddr': {u'city': u'Columbus', u'phoneExtension': None, u'country': u'USA', u'addrLine2': None, u'zipCode': u'43123', u'addrLine1': u'123 Test St', u'state': u'OH', u'phoneNumber': u'555-555-5555', u'email': u'example@2co.com', u'name': u'Testing Tester'}}
```

Comment: Usually, `successfully authorized` is not the same thing as `successfully charged`. I'm not super familiar with 2checkout, but the process for most payment processors is: (1) Validate credit card, (2) Receive a response that the credit card is valid (may include some kind of "token"), (3) Use the response data to send a "charge" request, (4) if you receive a success response at this step, redirect. **EDIT:** After reviewing your link, that is in fact how it works.

Comment: @rnevius Looks like I completed the step 2, I got the token and apparently the credit card is valid. I am wondering how to do a "charge request" in the step 3

Comment: It looks like that's covered in the "Create the Sale" section of that tutorial. If you look at the data being sent to 2checkout, it includes the `POST`ed token. Now that it sounds like you have it, you'll be able to use it with `twocheckout.Charge.authorize()`.

Comment: So actually, on second glance, "authorized" may == "charged". If you look in your dashboard, is there a record of the payment?

Comment: @rnevius I don't think 2checkout allows the record of payment with demo account :( I edited my question to include the response I got

Comment: Looks like it worked fine. You could now use a value from the dict to generate a custom message to the user, or redirect to a success page.

Comment: @rnevius Too bad that 2checkout does not allow demo sales to appear in the admin panel. Anyways, thank you) helped a lot